# Control Message Box for Data Validation in Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I've created a data validation in apps script for google sheets to prevent the red error flags from popping up. Now I need to control the message box wording. The code I wrote for the message box isn't working.

Here's what I have:

```
//set data validation
function myFunction() {
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('New CI').getRange('A1:AR');
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireTextContains('Edits must be made in the google form').setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}

  //create browser box
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    //range A1:AR5000
    e.source.getSheetName() == "New CI" &&
    e.range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 45 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5000
  ) {  
    if (e.changetype === 'EDIT' && e.value !== 'Edits must be made in the google form');{
      Browser.msgBox('Edits must be made in the google form');
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: I agree on what Cooper says here: if you do not want the values to be edited why not protect them directly? 
Share with us what you are trying to accomplish because maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: When you protect it directly, the viewer cannot expand/collapse column groups. The columns go up to 'AR'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just share your spreadsheet in read only mode.  And by the way there is no changeType in an onEdit() trigger event object and if you were using the change event it's spelled `changeType`.   It's also not a good idea to put a dialog in an onEdit() simple trigger because they must complete in 30 seconds.  So it  might be better to consider a toast.  But it looks like you don't want people to edit the spreadsheet so just share it with them in read only mode.

Comment: I'm fine sharing the file as read only but the table columns range from A:AR and I wanted to have column groups. If people access the file in view only they can't expand/collapse the groups

Answer (score 0):

The Browser.msgBox works perfectly like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  Browser.msgBox('Edits must be made in the google form');
}
```

In resume, your code runs perfectly, the problem that you are facing is either the if's conditions you have are never satisfied or you are not placing properly the trigger.

**First, check the if conditions:**

- Is it correct the following `if` condition?

```js
    if (e.changetype === 'EDIT' && e.value !== 'Edits must be made in the google form');
```

What you are saying here is that you will only show the msgBox if the event value is exactly equal to `Edits must be made....`. 
I do not think this is what you want, I believe that you want is that for any edit made on the spreadsheet the msgBox should appear. So, this should be enough:

```js
    if (e.changetype === 'EDIT');
```

- Is this first if condition correct?

```js
  if (
    //range A1:AR5000
    e.source.getSheetName() == "New CI" &&
    e.range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 45 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5000
  )
```

For me it looks okay if what you want is to show the msgBox only when someone edits the cells on the specified range and the specified spreadsheet 'New CI'.

Let me know if this solves your problem.